# Dockerizing PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker

So my devops friend set up an environment for my app using docker cloud. He set some temporary db passwords and told me to change them in `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-cloud.yml` files. My `docker-cloud.yml` file looks like this:

```
db:
  image: mdillon/postgis:9.6
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: temppasswd
    POSTGRES_USER: myuser
    POSTGRES_DB: mydb
web:
  autoredeploy: true
  image: myapp/myapp_api:latest
  ports:
    - "80:8000"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    DATABASE_NAME: mydb
    DATABASE_USER: myuser
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: temppasswd
cron:
  autoredeploy: true
  image: myapp/myapp_api:latest
  links:
    - db
  command: cron -f -L 15
```

He also told me to change the password in docker cloud stack and to do a redeploy which I did - with no effect. Meaning: new password doesn't work and I can still login with the old one. So how to change that darn password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSTGRES_USER is set up once when the container is first started. If you delete the container the next time you start it the database will reinitialise with your changes.

Deleting your container will delete all your data too. If you don't want to do this log in to the container when it's running and change the password manually.

```
psql -h <host> -U myuser
```

then

```
alter role myuser password 'temppasswd';
```